# basic scope on instagram API approved, but still only can get 20 results of photo

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

i have problem with my website using the instagram's API

i have submitted review for my website and it has been approved by Instagram with public scope.

[heres the screenshot of my client permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyNH4.png)

but yet i cant retrieve all of my instagram post in my website, it only shows 20 latest post.

this video can show you how my website works with the Instagram's API

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zy7mmgqDhjw

anyone can help me with this? sorry for my bad english before

Thank you very much :)

Comment: did u go live? or still in sandbox, you have to go live after getting approval

Comment: @krisrak yes,my app status is live in instagram developer

Comment: are you using `pagination.next_url` to get next 20?

Comment: @krisrak no, im not using pagination, does instagram API limits the results to 20 for each request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default you will only get 20 posts per API call. You can increase this by adding url param `&count=32`, this will give you up 32 posts (setting count more than 32 will just get you 32)

After that you have use the `pagination.next_url` in API response to get next set of posts.

Comment: thank you, it works. Now i just have to make the pagination to show the next set of posts.